# Correct version of movesense-mobile-lib

Tags: android, dfu, movesense

Which version of the movesense-mobile-lib works with shipped Movesense sensors when using DFU to update firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if You have new software version on Your Movesense, DFU is not working. Embedded guys working on it because seems it is not Android bug because Nordic App has the same problems.

If You have older version it should works fine so You are interested about code
on **master branch.**

But to be sure we are talking about the same issue can You post sw version?
You can read it from logs and put logs from error.

Example:

```
09-04 12:49:16.545 21186-21861/com.movesense.mds.sampleapp I/Komposti: Device /Info dump: {"Content": {"manufacturerName": "Suunto", "brandName": null, "productName": "SmartSensor2", "variant": "Unknown", "design": null, "hwCompatibilityId": "C", "serial": "ECKICFD7F724", "pcbaSerial": "UNKNOWN", "sw": "0.6.0", "hw": "UNKNOWN", "additionalVersionInfo": null, "addressInfo": [{"name": "BLE", "address": "E5-07-96-5E-94-CD"}], "apiLevel": "1"}}
```

Comment: This became irrevelant for now, I made a programming jig so I can flash code directly to sensor. :)